# Debugging Craft CMS templates on Visual Studio Code

Tags: craft3, templating, debugging

Is there a way to debug templates used in craft cms on visual studio code? I tried doing it but I just get this error:
"${workspaceFolder}' can not be resolved. Please open a folder."
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

There are so many Extensions available on visual studio code. You can install for the language snippets, for auto-suggest code, and for checking syntax. If you are looking for the debug page load process then you have to try the default debug toolbar of Craft CMS. To enable the default to debug toolbar you can go to the profile page -> Preferences from the control panel and then check the below 2 options.

1. Show the debug toolbar on the front end
2. Show the debug toolbar in the control panel

After enabling it will look like this.

[image]

I hope this will help.

Thanks.